# More efficient way of organising/structuring this array?

Tags: php

I receive this array of data and I have to structure it accordingly:

```
$data = array(
    'field-492396-label' => 'Field',
    'field-492396-default' => 'b',
    'field-885143-label' => 'Another Field',
    'field-885143-default' => 'a',
);
```

<sup>*As you can see, each of the inputs has a "custom" id that I'd like to order it by.*</sup>

I've got this working code, that generates it as I require, but I'm looking for/if there is a more efficient way of doing this:

```
$new = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key,'field-') !== false) {
        list($lister, $id, $field) = explode('-', $key);
        if(!isset($new[$id])) $new[$id] = array('id' => $id);
        $new[$id][$field] = $value;
    }
}
```

#### [`Working Demo`](http://www.tehplayground.com/#YvMN56hPT)

Is there a more efficient way of completing this and creating the new array? The structure I'm looking for is this:

```
Array
(
    [492396] => Array
        (
            [id] => 492396
            [label] => Field
            [default] => b
        )
    .....
)
```

Comment: Your code works fine and looks fine in terms of efficiency to me. What are you concerned about?

Comment: @scrowler Just trying to see if there is a more efficient method of doing it.

Comment: Unless the `$data` is too big, I don't think you need to spend time to optimize your code. Even when the `$data` is too big, the thing should be optimized is the data source.